# Авторизация на сайте

Tags: python, python-3.x

помогите пожалуйста разобраться с авторизацией при помощи скрипта. после чтения архива этого форума и гугления понялпримерно следующее:
до появления библиотеки request использовалась библиотека urllib. обычно приходилось смотреть исходный код формы авторизации, составлять словарь, состоящий изадреса отправки формы, значения из скрытого поля, логина, пароля. но после появления библиотеки request авторизация стала проще(необходимы только пароль и логин). скрипт выглядит так

```
import urllib
import pprint
import re
import requests

import bs4

r = requests.get('http://forum.saransk.ru/', auth=('sergey', 'passpass'))
print(r.status_code)
print(r)

url = 'http://forum.saransk.ru/'
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)

signLink = soup.find('a', {'id': 'sign_in'})
if signLink:
    print(signLink.prettify())
```

как видите, здесь я авторизуюсь и проверяю при помощи парсера есть ли на странице ссылка "вход". у авторизовавшегося пользователя её не должно быть. но в моём случае она есть. значит скрипт не работает. подскажите пожалуйста где я ошибся

вот что выводится на экран после запуска скрипта

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
200
<Response [200]>
<a href="http://forum.saransk.ru/index.php?app=core&amp;module=global&amp;section=login" id="sign_in" title="Войти">
 Войти
</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сервер помнит пользователей не по айпи какому-нибудь, а по cookie. Поэтому после авторизации надо их вытащить и предоставлять при каждом запросе.

Comment: поясните пожалуйста. сервер отличает авторизованного и не авторизованного пользователя по кукам конкретно на моём сайте или вообще? или не большинстве сайтов?

Comment: @Sergey Kalinin, на 99% сайтах. Есть альтернативные способы, но они, как правило, требуют участия javascript, флеша и прочего, что значительно усложняет разработку. Поэтому даже не глядя на этот сайт могу сказать, что вам нужны куки, 40% что нужная будет называться PHPSESSID.

Comment: @Sergey, я думал urllib умеет автоматически работать с сессиями.