# Python Requests: как повторно отправить POST-запрос по условию?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, requests, soap

Доброе время суток!

Я использую Requests для общения с SOAP сервисом:

```
try:
    response = requests_retry_session(session=s). \
    post(cf.ENDPOINT_URI, timeout=cf.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT,
    data=decoded_signed_request, headers=cf.HEADERS)
except Exception as ex:
    output_provider(2, cf.OP_CONN_ERROR, ex.__class__.__name__)
else:
    # Parse response
    output_provider(2, cf.OP_PARSE_MESSAGE, str(i[0]))
    charge_data = xml.parseString(response.content)

    result = charge_data.getElementsByTagName('SomeNode')[0]
```

И в зависимости от того какое значение ноды я получу в `result` после ответа от сервиса мне нужно решить: Отправить этот же POST-запрос n раз и ждать другой `result` или продолжить дальше.

Вопрос: Как лучше всего это сделать? `while`? Или есть какое-то более элегантное решение?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант через цикл:

```
while True:
    try:
        rs = requests_retry_session(session=s).post(
            cf.ENDPOINT_URI, 
            timeout=cf.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT,
            data=decoded_signed_request,
            headers=cf.HEADERS
        )
        
        # Parse response
        output_provider(2, cf.OP_PARSE_MESSAGE, str(i[0]))

        charge_data = xml.parseString(rs.content)        
        result = charge_data.getElementsByTagName('SomeNode')[0]
        
        # Выходим из цикла
        if result == 'OK':
            break

    except Exception as e:
        output_provider(2, cf.OP_CONN_ERROR, e.__class__.__name__)

        # NOTE: При ошибках можно завершить цикл:
        # break
        #
        # Или подождать перед следующей попыткой:
        # time.sleep(60)
```

В этом алгоритме удобно, что все содержимое цикла находится в try/except, а значит можно обработать разные ситуации и в зависимости от их типа (нет соединения с сервером, ошибка парсинга ответа и т.п.) решить -- продолжать цикл или нет.

Конечно, ситуации разные бывают, поэтому я показал простейший и надежный вариант проверки.

Comment: Буду благодарен если поможете с моим вопросом по такой же теме https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/299217/%d0%90%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b5?rq=1