# Как отправить данные post запросом в requests?

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests

Нужно отправить данные тут - https://login.yahoo.com/account/create?intl=ru

Пробовал:

```
data = {
'firstName': 'John',
'lastName': 'Vickers',
'yid': 'johnvickers',
'...': '...'
}
response = session.post(url, proxies=proxies, headers=HEADERS, data=data)
file = open('test.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
file.write(response.text)
```

Но в итоге в файле просто страница регистрации.

Comment: кстати, что не так? вы думаете, что при post запросе вам кто-то обязательно сам нажмет кнопку `продолжить`? к тому же вам нужно быть уверенным, что данные которые ожидает сервер хранятся именно по нужному вам идентификатору

Comment: @NEStenerusnester как тогда "нажать" на кнопку?

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
r = requests.post("ваш url", data=data)
```

библиотека requests (не забудьте установить) позволяет легко отправлять запросы как get так и post, для пост запросу нужно вызвать метод `post` библиотеки requests: `requests.post()` вам нужно 2 параметра: первый url нужной страницы, а второй это данные, они хранятся в атрибуте `data` и принимает этот атрибут ассоциативный массив как у вас, ваша переменная называется `data`поэтому я пишу `data=data` если бы данные для отправки лежали в переменной `mass`, то я бы написал `data = mass` (жую для новичков)  а возвращаемое записывается в переменную `r`

Comment: Буду благодарен если поможете с моим вопросом https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/299217/%d0%90%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b5?rq=1